# can mailboxSize be used to count number of messages received by a scala actor?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

I have a problem in which I have to count the number of messages received by several scala actors (I am using all the actors as instances of the same Actor class), and also maintain their counts separately for each actor. The actors send the message to each other and once a certain number of messages are received by an actor, I should stop the communication between actors. Is there any way in which I can do this in scala?

Comment: Easiest way I can think of is keep a `var numOfMessages = 0` in the constructor, and each time the actor acts on a message, increment the `numOfMessages`.

Comment: @adelbertc thanks for the reply. Is it possible to send a message from an Actor Instance to another instance of the same Actor?

Comment: Yes, it does not matter that the 2 actors are of the same class. You will need to somehow communicate to one actor the existence of the other actor by passing it something analogous to an `ActorRef` in Akka. If you are using Scala Actors I am not sure how that is handled - if you are interested in Actors in Scala I would recommend checking out Akka which will replace Scala Actors in Scala 2.10.